# C# Call a function from a Com interop loaded with Reflection, gives Type mismatch

Tags: c#, dynamic, com-interop

I have a project where i need to call a Dll Interop from C#.

```
dynamic Sql = variableFromTheEntryPoint;
string query = Sql.FormatSQLExt(ref text, objs);
```

The Interop Declaration of Sql object have this method like this:

```
[DispId(1610809348)]
string FormatSQLExt(ref string strSQLSt, params object[] vntParams);
```

This code would work if i reference the DLL in the project and use the code:

```
Interop.StdPlatBS800.StdBSSQL Sql = variableFromTheEntryPoint as Interop.StdPlatBS800.StdBSSQL;
string query = Sql.FormatSQLExt(ref text, objs);
```

I can't use that way because the interop is an ERP that have weekly updates and i can't controll when those are made.
I am already using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve to fix most of the updates. it works fine and most of the updates of the Dll Interop don't break the code.

The problem is when the Interface of the Interop changes and then my code break because the Interface of my Dll is diferent from the new version.

i would like to have my code stop working only when the methods i use from the interop was changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I would consider platform invoke rather than COM interop if possible.  It looks like your COM interop code includes `[DispId]` attributes, which could change if the interface changes, as you seem to be experiencing.  There are a number of other identifiers that are part of the COM assembly registration as well.

In contrast, platform invoke via `[DllImport]` may simplify this sort of late binding.  Basic documentation is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc(v=vs.110).aspx).  You would create a class with methods declarations like:

```
[DllImport("YourVendorLibrary.dll")]
public static extern string FormatSQLExt(string strSQLSt, object[] vntParams);
```

Note the [implications of using a full or relative path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.value(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `[DllImport]` statement.  If you use a full path, changing the path requires recompilation.

Comment: Thx for the info, but Since "FormatSQLExt" is inside a class StdBSSQL witch is inside StdPlatBS800, how will DllImport know where that function is declared?